# why is writing int(input()) on two lines different from one line?

Tags: python, input

I am writing code to solve the following problem on CodeChef: https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST/

The problem itself is not important as such, my question is that I submitted two answer:

```
1: 

x,y = input().split()
x = int(x)
y = float(y)

if x % 5 == 0 and x <= y - 0.50:
    print(y - (x+0.50))
else:
    print(y)


2. 
    x = int(input(x))
    y = float(input(y))
    
    if x % 5 == 0 and x <= y - 0.50:
        print(y - (x+0.50))
    else:
        print(y)
```

As you can see everything is the same except for the initiation of x and y- while the first batch of code is accepted, the second one runs into a NZEC runtime error. Any idea what the difference is between the two? Is it because of the way the input is inserted by the CodeChef website?

Comment: `input()` reads one line. The first code reads one line (I suppose `x` and `y` are on one line). The second code reads one line with `x` and `y` then tries to read the second line (which I suppose isn't there).

Comment: The second solution will fail because of a NameError: `...input(x)...` What is the parameter x  for input? Same for y then. And the next problem is a probably what @YevhenKuzmovych said

Comment: Thanks both. Ocaso, so if I changed it to x = int(input()) and y = float(input()) - then this will resolve the NameError? Also, does input() always read one line?

Comment: Yes, it will resolve the name error, but not the problem, that the input is given in one line (e.g. `30 120.0`) which will make the `int(...)` fail. So for the codechef problem the two line solution will not work, but from a "developer point of view" both versions will be the same.

Comment: Thanks Ocaso for the explanation. One last question if I may- how do I know when the input will be given in one line? Because looking at the CodeChef website for the problem, it doesn't say anything about it- it merely says we have X and Y as inputs and their constraints.

Comment: @hefufhiwh The examples at CodeChef give a clear hint of how the input should be.

Comment: Yes, @Matthias is right, although I think CodeChef should state that explicitly in the description.